# jquery mobile switches back to index on refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, refresh, reload

I'm a bit in a sticky situation.

I'm developing a mobile website with jQuery mobile 1.1.1. Its a pure javascript html5 implementation.

**The anatomy is like follow:**

- 1 HTML page called `index.html` containing a complete HTML structure with header, all includes (javascript/css etc), body etc. This page redirects via `$.mobile.changePage('login.hml')` to a login site.
- X sub-sites containing only `<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="x" data-title="x">` and site specific html/javascript code.

This works fine so far. The only problem is, when I refresh the page (with <kbd>F5</kbd> for example), I'm always redirected to the login site after the refresh.

---

**Example:**

I'm on the following site (url):

```
http://mysite/mobile/web/#/mobile/web/list.html
```

then, I press <kbd>F5</kbd> for refreshing the page.

The refresh is done and afterwards i get redirected to:

```
http://mysite/mobile/web/#/mobile/web/login.html
```

How could I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When refreshing you page your browser will interpret the URL as the page you want to display as `http://mysite/mobile/web/` which is why you open your `index.html`, which redirects you to `login.html`.

There are 2 possible fixes:

1. modify your redirection so that you parse the target URL and identify the intended location (everything after the #, in you example `/mobile/web/list.html`) and redirect to this given page.
   You should of course first check if your user is logged properly in order to redirect to login.html if necessary.
2. you can also modify the URL used by your list.html page so that it properly uses `http://mysite/mobile/web/list.html` (if that is indeed where your file is stored). I would not favor this approach as it will require you to add all the proper header information in this page also, and I feel it easier to conform to the JQuery Mobile spirit by having a single entry point to your site, handling dynamically the destination of your user

Comment: The problem was something different. I used  following code snipet on the index page: 
'$(document).ready(function () {//$.mobile.changePage('login.html');
});'